# Mongoid error in Padrino when attempting to connect from Heroku to MongoHQ

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongoid, padrino, mongohq

I keep getting an Mongoid::Errors::InvalidDatabase - Database should be a Mongo::DB, not NilClass

from a padrino app that I've got working on dev locally but which refuses to connect to MongoHQ. I've using padrino 0.9.23 and Mongoid 2.0.0. Stumped as to what is going wrong here.

```
#database.rb 
require 'uri' 
if ENV["MONGOHQ_URL"] 
  mongo_uri = URI.parse(ENV["MONGOHQ_URL"]) 
  ENV['MONGOID_HOST']     = mongo_uri.host 
  ENV['MONGOID_PORT']     = mongo_uri.port.to_s 
  ENV["MONGOID_USERNAME"] = mongo_uri.user 
  ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] = mongo_uri.password 
  ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] = mongo_uri.path.gsub("/", "") 
else 
  host = 'localhost' 
  port = Mongo::Connection::DEFAULT_PORT 
  database_name = case Padrino.env 
    when :development then 'tweetup_dev' 
    when :production  then 'tweetup' 
    when :test        then 'tweetup_test' 
  end 
end
```

Both insertions via a rake task (to test for db connectivity) and the 
app trying to pull from the db in heroku continually fail with this 
error:

```
2011-04-09T08:02:29+00:00 app[web.1]: Mongoid::Errors::InvalidDatabase 
- Database should be a Mongo::DB, not NilClass.: 
2011-04-09T08:02:29+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/ 
gems/mongoid-2.0.0/lib/mongoid/config.rb:195:in `master' 
2011-04-09T08:02:29+00:00 app[web.1]:  (eval):2:in `master'
```

I can confirm the database is up and running on MongoHQ and I've 
created a document via web interface in it via MongoHQ remote connection via the supplied details from heroku config --long details.

Stumped at this point s to what the problem is.

Anybody have any clues or pointers as to what I may be doing wrong 
here? Have the various config options changed in mongoid as of 2.0.0? 
I should mention this is the first time I've tried to use MongoHQ with 
Mongoid.

At this point, I'm about to punt, spin up an Amazon EC2 instance and 
just use a localhost MongoDB but ultimately running this on heroku and with MongoHQ makes a lot more sense.

thanks for any help,
Daryl.

Comment: Do you not setup a mongoid.yml file when using mongoid with padrino? I am just a little confused by that file because if it finds the ENV variable it sets more ENV variables and if not it sets local variables ... I just never see those used anywhere.

Comment: With padrino and mongoid there is a database.rb fiel which reflect the second block after the else. No mongoid.yml file.

Comment: And I think you may have hit on it. Doh... accidentally deleted a critical line out of the file to create the Mongoid.conecntion. Be right back... Am going to face palmslap if that's what it is. =<